# Linking code compiled with VC++10 to code compiled with VC++9

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Our project uses VC++9 with VS2008, and we want to make the switch to VC++10 with VS2010 to use the new features. Unfortunately, some of our dependencies were built with VC++9, and recompiling them with VC++10 is not possible at the moment for various reasons. Since we really want to make the switch, is there was a way to simply link with those libraries, or is there no compatibility between VC++10 and VC++9 binaries?

EDIT: The actual dependencies are [BWAPI](http://code.google.com/p/bwapi/) and [BWTA](http://code.google.com/p/bwta/). In the case of BWAPI, it's not a problem, but BWTA depends in [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/), and that's what's giving us trouble. Trying to link with it yields a bunch of linking errors.

Comment: This is much easier to answer after you actually try it and tell us what is going wrong.  It is not impossible but making the call requires a *lot* more info from you.

Answer (score 1):

In general you are out of luck unless the dependencies are COM modules or dlls that export only "pure" C functions.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio releases are allowed to break ABI compatibility. This means the exported and internal signature of C++ classes is different, and passing for example a `std::string` from a binary compiled with one version to a binary compiled with a different version might not have the expected result. In short: do not rely on this working. If it does, you're lucky, but in "undefined behavior" territory at the runtime level. Just fix your code to build with VS2010. It's probably broken to start with.

Comment: It's not our code. In fact our code builds just fine. The problem is a few external libraries we're using.

Answer (score 0):

well in the case of a 3rd party lib that you cannot change, the typical answer is to wrap them with a simple dll that is built with VC2008 and calls the 3rd party for you. You then have control over what is exposed, so you can fall back to a 'standardised' mechanism that works with both linkers. This is almost always C function calls as C is very standardised.

The problem is MS changing the ABI of compiled C++, and I guess with the standards committee not providing a standard way of calling C++ binaries.

Looking at GCAL this doesn't seem to be a good answer for you, the best you can do in such cases is to contact GCAL and wait for a rebuilt binary.

---

But I just checked - its *open source*, rebuild it yourself. Not only that, it already supports VS2010 so rebuild should be easy.